# Riemannian submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is uniquely characterized by it's riemannian metric?

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, submanifold

I have an intuition which doesn't mean is correct. Suppose we have $\mathbb{R}^n$ seen as a riemannian manifold with it's standard riemannian metric (i.e. the euclidean one).

Suppose we have a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (without boundary) call it $M$ we can define a riemannian metric $g$ by inheriting it from $\mathbb{R}^n$.

What I wonder now is if we fix the Riemannian metric is it possible to uniquely define the submanifold?

I think an answer might be yes, but I wouldn't know how to prove or disprove it.

Any reference you can suggest?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but I think it's not true.  Hint:  A Riemannian metric on $S^1$ is completely characterized by its length.

Comment: What about up to isometries? Can I get an equivalence class?

Comment: Before I try to answer, is this a proper rephrasing of your original question:  Suppose $(S,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold which is isometric to a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Then, apart from precomposing with isometries of $S$ or postcomposing with isometries of $\mathbb{R}^n$, can there be other isometric embeddings of $(S,g)$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @JasonDeVito, that’s how I interpreted the question.

Comment: @Deane:  If that's the case, my first comment seems to provide a myriad of counterexamples.  Namely, suppose $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ is any knot which doesn't contain the origin for simplifity.  Then there is a unique $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^+$ with $\lambda K$ isometric to the usual metric on $S^1$, where $\lambda K = \{\lambda k: k\in K\}$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito, agreed. But the really interesting case is for a 2-dimensional submanifold in Euclidean 3-space.

Comment: @Deane:  I agree entirely!  Basically all I know about this case is a) if the metric on $M$ is positively curved, one does have rigidity, b) there are metrics which don't have rigidity, and c) this is an active area of research.  (And I hope you don't mind, but I just took the liberty of viewing your profile, leading to your homepage.  You seem way better qualified than me to write a coherent response to this question!)

Comment: @JasonDeVito, there was a time when I might have been considered an "expert" in this area, since there is so little known.

Comment: I think what I was trying to explain/ask was more you have the metric and if somewhat you can retrieve the whole manifold up to certain conditions. Or maybe if you have a smooth bilinear function if can uniquely associate a manifold to it, or an equivalence class.